# Google Analytics to Big Query data-What is the SQL code from Custom Dimension with transaction?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

[image: [com/H3alV.png]

How to see the data above in Big Query-The tables are there since an year.
What code should I use to see the above result?

User subscription status is Session based dimension which has made transactions.

I have enabled data in Big Query but how to see the exact the same results in BQ.?

Comment: Data transfer from Google Analytics to Big Query usually takes one day, and it is transferred in partitions (days). Check your core and custom tables in BigQuery that may respond to your request.

Comment: @highlytrainedbadger the tables are there since an year.
I am asking what is the code to get this.

Comment: Check the answer please.

Comment: @highlytrainedbadger it doesnt not give the custom dimensions and gives me null

Answer (score 0):

Try code below. Change table name and date interval according to your request.

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
date,
SUM(totals.visits) AS visits,
SUM(totals.pageviews) AS pageviews,
SUM(totals.transactions) AS transactions,
SUM(totals.transactionRevenue)/1000000 AS revenue
FROM `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_*`
WHERE
_TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20160801' AND '20170731'
GROUP BY date
ORDER BY date ASC
```

These documents could be useful for you before posting questions:
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/4419694?hl=tr
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437719?hl=tr

Answer (score 0):

For custom dimensions on session scope write a subquery that runs on the unnested array.

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT
  date,
  -- select one value from unnested array
  (SELECT value FROM UNNEST(customDimensions) WHERE index=4) AS cd4,
  SUM(totals.transactions) AS transactions,
FROM 
  `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_*`
WHERE
  _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20160801' AND '20160802'
GROUP BY 
  date, cd4
ORDER BY 
  date ASC
```

you need to change the condition in the subquery to your custom dimension index